# Selenium Webdriver get stuck when running a bunch of Unit Testcases in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium

I deployed a test project using Selenium and Unit test of Visual Studio 2013.
When I run a single testcase, it worked properly. But when running a playlist with more than 15 TCs, they were usually stuck and user cannot login into the system.

Does anyone know of an actual solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have a playlist of Selenium test cases in Visual Studio. I create a fresh instance of the Selenium WebDriver for each test case. This is also good because this way I get a fresh browser window for each test case, so everything is as if I only run a single test case, no matter how long my playlist is.

Try that!

Comment: Thanks Kimmy, I have the [AssemblyInitialize] and [TestInitialize] for each TC. So when running a TC, it will create a new Webdriver and clear it after running. But It still stuck. I'm using IEDriver

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember why, but for the InternetExplorerDriver I always add the InitialBrowserUrl option:

```
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    InitialBrowserUrl = "about:blank",
});
```

Maybe you should try so, too!